# google api place search not working node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get the google maps api places to work. I found an npm module that makes it easy to get it connected to node.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleplaces

I downloaded the module and added the api key in the config.js file like it said.
Then in my main.js file which is basically the server. I do

```
const googleplaces = require("googleplaces");
parameters = {
        location: [60.164315, 24.936667],
        types: "restaurant"
      };
googleplaces.placeSearch(parameters, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw error;
    assert.notEqual(response.results.length, 0, "Place search must not return 0 results");
});
```

I get a error of : 
`TypeError: googleplaces.placeSearch is not a function`

I checked the node module and can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this example here](https://github.com/Srirangan/googleplaces.js/blob/master/test/GooglePlacesTest.js), you have to create a new object from the googleplaces module you've required. You're just calling it directly, which is why the method doesn't exist; it can only be called on an the object instantiated with the config settings from `config.js`.

Replace this:

```
const googlePlaces = require('googleplaces');
```

...with this:

```
const config = require('./config.js');
const GooglePlaces = require('googleplaces');
const googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces(config.apiKey, config.outputFormat);
```

Comment: but config isnt in ./config.js its in the nodel model lib/test/config.js

Comment: Okay, then require `lib/test/config.js`. I don't know the location of your config files ha, I'm sure you can fill in the spaces.